# AWS EMR cloudformation spark-env Encountered unsupported property properties

Tags: apache-spark, aws-cloudformation

I was trying to point spark to use python3 in EMR.

I added the below code in our config files

```
    Resources:
  PFJEMR:
    Type: 'AWS::EMR::Cluster'
    Properties:
      Configurations:
       - Classification: 'spark-defaults'
         ConfigurationProperties:  
          spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors: 2
          spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors: 2
          spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors: 20
          spark.port.maxRetries: 50
       - Classification: 'spark-env'
         Configurations: 
          - Classification: 'export'
            properties:
             PYSPARK_PYTHON: '/usr/bin/python3'
```

here is the json version:

```
 "Configurations": [
                    {
                        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
                        "ConfigurationProperties": {
                            "spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors": 2,
                            "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors": 2,
                            "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors": 20,
                            "spark.port.maxRetries": 50
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Classification": "spark-env",
                        "Configurations": [
                            {
                                "Classification": "export",
                                "properties": {
                                    "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
```

But while creating stacks, it keeps giving me Encountered unsupported property properties error.

I am sure it is coming from the spark-env part since I successfully tested the spark-default part.

Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried  ``` - Classification: 'spark-env'
     ConfigurationProperties: 
         PYSPARK_PYTHON: '/usr/bin/python3' ``` it doesn't give me an error but it don't anything either

Comment: basically what I want to achieve is the same effect as run this command in EMR sudo sed -i -e '$a\export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

Comment: Try renaming `properties` to `ConfigurationProperties`